# Running an scala class from sbt console

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to run

```
object main extends App {
...
}
```

from `$ sbt console`, just so that I dont have to manually set the classpath

Comment: `main.main(Array())`. (Note that the standard naming convention dictates `object Main`, not `object main`.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `:load` to load the scala file and then invoke the main function explicitly.

Test.scala is in the directory where sbt console is running

```
$ cat Test.scala
object Main extends App {
 println("Hello")
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> :load Test.scala
Loading Test.scala...
defined module Main


scala> Main.main(Array())
Hello
```

In your case you have to load the scala file the following way

```
scala> :load <path of scala file>

scala> <main_object_name>.main(Array())
```

Instead of empty arguments you could give main arguments in case your main function is anticipating.